# Javascript call function in order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is what i expect to happen, i am using anulgarjs as controller

1.when a button is clicked, call the http post function and return a boolean value

2.the returned boolean is a checking condition

3.if ture, attach a url to a html element of href attribute , and clicked immediately

4.if false, a model pop up

```
$scope.checking = function(arg){
  $http.post('path/').success(function(r){
     // r is a boolean value 
    deferral.resolve(r);
  });
  return deferral.promise;
};
```

second function

```
$scope.secondfun =function(){
  url= 'someurl'
  $scope.checking().then(function(r){
    if(r){
      $('#htmlelement').attr('href', url);
    }
    else{
      $('#somemodal').modal('toggle');
    }
  });
}
```

problem: the order is not as i expected
model or url don't show up right after the button clicked. Instead,  it shows up when i clicked the button again

Meanwhile , as i am not sure i've used the promise correctly , i tried something like this on the second function :

```
$scope.secondfun = function(){
  url= 'someurl';
  var bool = false;
  $scope.checking().then(function(r){
    bool = r;
  });
  if(bool){
    $('#htmlelement').attr('href', url);
  }
  else{
    $('#somemodal').modal('toggle');
  }
};
```

problem: the if clause execute before the bool is assigned , bool is undefined

So , i just need something help to solve the problem

Comment: In your `checking` function, `return $http.post('path/')` should do the trick

Comment: I believe tried to just return the http promise, but the problem still exist , the URL or model just not show up immediately and when I click it again it show up , so seem the html attribute updated but not execute on the same click event

Comment: It seems I can use a document.getelementbyid and call click function to solve this , but any suggestions that it won't work like I expected

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your checking function to this

```
$scope.checking = function(arg){

return $http.post('path/')
  .then(function(r) {
    return r;
  },function(error){
    return error;
  });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just return the promise when checking

```
$scope.checking = function(arg){
  return $http.post('path/');
}
```

And then use that promise as you are doing already

```
$scope.secondfun = function(){
  url= 'someurl'
  $scope.checking().then(function(r){
    if(r){
      $('#htmlelement').attr('href', url);
    }else{
      $('#somemodal').modal('toggle');
    }
  });
}
```